# Handle bluetooth connection and disconnection between phone and car

Tags: java, bluetooth, localization, connection, disconnect

I want to handle the Connection and disconnection of Bluetooth devices on my android java app, but i need some help, I must catch the current location, where the disconnection occurs between the stored Bluetooth address and the phone (that has the app) and store it in my database.
In my app I already have a database, in which I can store the Bluetooth address of each device.

The question is: How can I catch the current location of the disconnection between app and car and store it in my firestore database ? then how can I call it in order to show it in my MapActivtity?

Comment: None of your sentences contain a question mark, so where is your question? And above all, where is the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the error? Or maybe your question is simply [off topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?